# 12v 4.8Ah DC regulated to BOTH 5v with 1.9A and 5v 5A

Tags: voltage-regulator, raspberry-pi, amperage, battery-operated, high-current

I am in the process of designing a circuit. I am unsure how to design a regulator to power the system.

[image: Diagram]

I don't know of a way to be able to achieve what is shown in the diagram above. Looking online I have found similar problems with 12v to high current voltage regulators. I don't know how to design a circuit for this specific set up nor which regulator to use.

It will use a [PCA9685](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/PCA9685.pdf) to drive 16 servos via I2C on a raspberry pi. The total amperage for all of the servos is from 3760mA to 4460mA.

I could separate the systems power supplies into two batteries but this would be better, if possible. If I do need to use different power supplies could I have recommendations for the specs and which regulator to use?

Does anyone know what regulator specifically could meet these requirements and how the circuit would be configured?

EDIT: Thinking about it, maybe the current needed for the PCA9685 will not be as much as originally thought if due to I2C the servos aren't underload at the same time. Am I thinking correctly here? This would decrease the current needed dramatically.

Comment: R U Sure that's the right PCA part An LED driver for a servo.

Comment: @Trevor, LED driver, well its a "16-channel, 12-bit PWM" that can drive a load of 25mA. So it is suitable for servo applications as well.

Comment: yup..just checking it was not a typo.

Comment: cathe - "*which regulator to use?*", "*what regulator specifically could meet these requirements*" Be careful. You are turning your question into a *shopping question* and those are specifically not allowed ([see the site help](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). That's partly because such recommendations can quickly become obsolete and are very localised e.g. I have seen someone spend lots of time designing a circuit in an answer, for a specific IC. The response from the person asking the question was effectively - that's useless, I can't get that IC in my location :-(

Comment: You're expecting this to run for about an hour, right?

Comment: Yeah about that long I would imagine. Just not sure how to set it up

Answer (score 1):

You need one, or two, buck regulators.

You can get away with one, but two may be better if you want to keep the high current loads on a separate power bus.

Why you are using LED drivers to drive servos however, I am not sure.

Comment: Section 7.7 and fig 26 and 27 show how this can use external drivers, so using it for servos may not be the worst option.

Comment: It is advertised to be able to driver 16 servos shown here: https://www.adafruit.com/product/815

Comment: Thanks for the reply btw, I'll have a look at buck regulators.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the two loads isolated from each other, you need two regulators - one capable of delivering at least 2 Amps at 5 Volts, and the other capable of delivering at least 5 Amps at 5 Volts.  The loads will determine the actual current drawn from each supply.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you know of any regulators in particular that would work for my situation?